# Java Hashmap removing data and replacing with new ones

Tags: java, hashmap

Say I have HashMap called `HashMap<Integer, List<String>> storeR`; and it stores "11,name1,name2" and I want to change that 11 to some other number? how should i do it? Hope you guys can help me with it. Thank you.

Comment: Is `11` the key? or a part of value

Comment: 11 is like ID for name1 and name2..i store integer and string

Comment: @RohitJain 11 is like ID for name1 and name2..i store integer and string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that you're trying to change the *key*, you basically need to remove the old entry and insert a new one. You can use the fact that `remove` returns the value from the entry which is being removed:

```
List<String> oldValue = map.remove(oldKey);
map.put(newKey, oldValue);
```

Comment: the newKey is already in the HashMap and have some data also and it is overwritten with oldKey's data..how do i make the newKey to store both its' own original data and oldkey's data?

Comment: @user2064467: You'd need to use something like `newKeyValue.addAll(oldKeyValue)`. You should look at using `Multimap` in Guava though, if you're working with a lot of maps storing multiple values per key.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the old key, and add the list with new key.